# Finding Highest Number in a list. If statements not working. Have results. Java

Tags: java, arrays, variables, if-statement

I want to find the students with the three highest averages print their name and their average. It seems to find the highest for all three place. I know there may be better ways to do this, if you choose to explain a better way please explain why this doesn't work first. Only the last statements in the results arent working.

the results are: 
The class average for test 1 is: 88
The class average for test 2 is: 62
The class average for test 3 is: 79
Alex's three test average is 85
Barry's three test average is 77
Cindy's three test average is 81
Deb's three test average is 72
Eric's three test average is 75
Fran's three test average is 63
Gary's three test average is 74
Helen's three test average is 83
The student with the highest average is: Alex with a average of: 85
The student with the second highest average is: Alex with a average of: 85
The student with the third highest average is: Alex with a average of: 85

My code is:

```
package lab3;

public class third {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = { "Alex", "Barry", "Cindy", "Deb", "Eric", "Fran",
                "Gary", "Helen" };

        int[][] grades = { { 77, 83, 96 }, { 88, 67, 78 }, { 92, 77, 76 },
                { 94, 42, 81 }, { 99, 54, 72 }, { 90, 46, 54 }, { 76, 59, 88 },
                { 94, 69, 88 } };
        int S = grades.length; // number of students
        int E = grades[0].length; // number of exams
        int sum = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < S; a++) {
            sum = sum + grades[a][0];
        }
        System.out.println("The class average for test 1 is: " + sum / S);
        sum = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < S; a++) {
            sum = sum + grades[a][1];
        }
        System.out.println("The class average for test 2 is: " + sum / S);
        sum = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < S; a++) {
            sum = sum + grades[a][2];
        }
        System.out.println("The class average for test 3 is: " + sum / S);
        for (int a = 0; a < S; a++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int b = 0; b < E; b++) {
                sum = sum + grades[a][b];
            }
            System.out
                    .println(names[a] + "'s three test average is " + sum / 3);

        }
        int firstPlace = 0;
        String firstPlaceName = "";
        int secondPlace = 0;
        String secondPlaceName = "";
        int thirdPlace = 0;
        String thirdPlaceName = "";
        for (int u = 0; u < S; u++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int t = 0; t < E; t++) {
                sum = sum + grades[u][t];
            }
            if (sum > firstPlace) {
                firstPlace = sum;
                firstPlaceName = names[u];
                secondPlace = firstPlace;
                secondPlaceName = firstPlaceName;
                thirdPlace = secondPlace;
                thirdPlaceName = secondPlaceName;

            }
            if (sum > secondPlace && sum != firstPlace) {
                secondPlace = sum;
                secondPlaceName = names[u];
                thirdPlace = secondPlace;
                thirdPlaceName = secondPlaceName;

            }
            if (sum > thirdPlace && sum != firstPlace && sum != secondPlace) {
                thirdPlace = sum;
                thirdPlaceName = names[u];

            }
        }
        System.out.println("The student with the highest average is: "+firstPlaceName+" with a average of: "+firstPlace/3);
        System.out.println("The student with the second highest average is: "+secondPlaceName+" with a average of: "+secondPlace/3);
        System.out.println("The student with the third highest average is: "+thirdPlaceName+" with a average of: "+thirdPlace/3);

    }
}
```

I'm a beginner just learning control structures thats why I'm doing it this way.

Okay, so I realized what I was trying to do is more simple but, this is still not correct.

my new code is:
    package lab3;

```
public class third {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = { "Alex", "Barry", "Cindy", "Deb", "Eric", "Fran",
                "Gary", "Helen" };

        int[][] grades = { { 77, 83, 96 }, { 88, 67, 78 }, { 92, 77, 76 },
                { 94, 42, 81 }, { 99, 54, 72 }, { 90, 46, 54 }, { 76, 59, 88 },
                { 94, 69, 88 } };
        int S = grades.length; // number of students
        int E = grades[0].length; // number of exams
        int sum = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < S; a++) {
            sum = sum + grades[a][0];
        }
        System.out.println("The class average for test 1 is: " + sum / S);
        sum = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < S; a++) {
            sum = sum + grades[a][1];
        }
        System.out.println("The class average for test 2 is: " + sum / S);
        sum = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < S; a++) {
            sum = sum + grades[a][2];
        }
        System.out.println("The class average for test 3 is: " + sum / S);
        for (int a = 0; a < S; a++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int b = 0; b < E; b++) {
                sum = sum + grades[a][b];
            }
            System.out
                    .println(names[a] + "'s three test average is " + sum / 3);

        }
        int firstPlace = 0;
        String firstPlaceName = "";
        int secondPlace = 0;
        String secondPlaceName = "";
        int thirdPlace = 0;
        String thirdPlaceName = "";
        for (int u = 0; u < S; u++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int t = 0; t < E; t++) {
                sum = sum + grades[u][t];
            }
            if (sum > firstPlace) {
                firstPlace = sum;
                firstPlaceName = names[u];



            }
            else if(sum>secondPlace){
                secondPlace=sum;
                secondPlaceName=names[u];
            }
            else if(sum>thirdPlace){
                thirdPlace=sum;
                thirdPlaceName=names[u];

            }
            else{

            }
        }
        System.out.println("The student with the highest average is: "+firstPlaceName+" with a average of: "+firstPlace/3);
        System.out.println("The student with the second highest average is: "+secondPlaceName+" with a average of: "+secondPlace/3);
        System.out.println("The student with the third highest average is: "+thirdPlaceName+" with a average of: "+thirdPlace/3);

    }
}
```

and my results are:
The class average for test 1 is: 88
The class average for test 2 is: 62
The class average for test 3 is: 79
Alex's three test average is 85
Barry's three test average is 77
Cindy's three test average is 81
Deb's three test average is 72
Eric's three test average is 75
Fran's three test average is 63
Gary's three test average is 74
Helen's three test average is 83
The student with the highest average is: Alex with a average of: 85
The student with the second highest average is: Helen with a average of: 83
The student with the third highest average is: Eric with a average of: 75

Okay I got a code that works, I could have just added changing the places but did it a different way. Where I just set the highest number to 0 when i find it.
    package lab3;

```
public class third {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = { "Alex", "Barry", "Cindy", "Deb", "Eric", "Fran",
                "Gary", "Helen" };

        int[][] grades = { { 77, 83, 96 }, { 88, 67, 78 }, { 92, 77, 76 },
                { 94, 42, 81 }, { 99, 54, 72 }, { 90, 46, 54 }, { 76, 59, 88 },
                { 94, 69, 88 } };
        int S = grades.length; // number of students
        int E = grades[0].length; // number of exams
        int sum = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < S; a++) {
            sum = sum + grades[a][0];
        }
        System.out.println("The class average for test 1 is: " + sum / S);
        sum = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < S; a++) {
            sum = sum + grades[a][1];
        }
        System.out.println("The class average for test 2 is: " + sum / S);
        sum = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < S; a++) {
            sum = sum + grades[a][2];
        }
        System.out.println("The class average for test 3 is: " + sum / S);
        double[] sg = new double[S];
        for (int a = 0; a < S; a++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int b = 0; b < E; b++) {
                sum = sum + grades[a][b];
            }
            sg[a] = sum;
            System.out
                    .println(names[a] + "'s three test average is " + sum / 3);

        }
        int firstPlace = 0;
        String firstPlaceName = "";
        int count = 0;
        int remover = 0;
        while (count != 3) {
            count = count + 1;
            remover = 0;
            firstPlace = 0;
            for (int u = 0; u < S; u++) {
                sum = (int) sg[u];
                if (sum > firstPlace) {
                    firstPlace = sum;
                    firstPlaceName = names[u];
                    remover = u;

                }
            }
            System.out.println("The student with the" + "# " + count
                    + " highest average is: " + firstPlaceName
                    + " with a average of: " + firstPlace / 3);
            sg[remover] = 0;
            System.out.println(sg[remover]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are using an object-oriented language. You don't need to use parallel arrays to accomplish your task. How about you create a `Student` class which will store the name and their grades? You can also have multiple methods in your `Student` class which will do various different things, such as calculating the average.

Answer (score 0):

All those if statements are going to be checked consecutively; do you actually want them all to be checked? Or should they be else ifs?

You can read up on if statements in the Java Documents and Tutorials:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Update: You can remove the final else statement as it does nothing. While your conditions have been fixed, the removal of the additional assignments within the if statements caused you to drop values. Put the

```
third = second;
second = first;
first = newHighest;
```

style assignments back in (this is pseudocode, you'll need to modify it to actually fit your variables). Also consider the order I listed them and ask yourself why you'd want to do the last assignment first.